# Precompiling Handlebars Templates from within VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, handlebars.js

This year I've started moving to Visual Studio 2015 from Visual Studio 2013. In vs2013 the brilliant Webessentials plugin allowed me to right click->compile any handlebars templates in my project, however I cannot do this in vs2015. I have installed Webessentials and Webcompiler plugins, but it looks like there's no support for it.

My question is, is there any automated plugin that will give me the same ability in VS2015? I really don't want to install grunt or gulp and add watcher tasks, we work from the server. I know it's possible but really the right click -> compile was so good I really hope it's going to be added back in or there's perhaps another tool.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have run into the same problem.

Comment: I didn't :( It is the *only* thing missing for me in vs2015. I even asked Mads Kristensen if he was planning on adding it back in to Web Essentials, but he said there was too much churn in that area. If you find something please let me know! At the moment I still use vs2013 to do the templates, and vs2015 for everything else. It really is a majorly helpful piece of functionality.

Comment: I will let u know. I too am using VS2013 just for HBS compilation.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be included in the next release of WebCompiler extension as part of WebEssensial package.

You can however, compile the source code for now and use it already.

https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/commit/dc1f55396be90ef0da0d45442edc3019250a5a48